# phpMyAdmin error messages with dot.gif on left sidebar

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm working with phpMyAdmin in localhost and this days getting this error messages:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

Also, on left sidebar I see some small images (`dot.gif`) before two database names. I tried to copy them, but it seems impossible, it is just 1x1 px.

phpMyAdmin version - `4.8.3 (up to date)`

What are this messages and how to resolve them?

Thanks.

Comment: dot.gif might be shown if there's a problem showing an icon. How have you installed phpMyAdmin, through a package manager, as part of an installed kit like WAMP or XAMPP, or by downloading from source and uncompressing yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The controluser message is probably related to the phpMyAdmin configuration storage (https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage). Take a look at your phpMyAdmin configuration file, `config.inc.php`; I suspect you'll see some lines like

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = 'somevalue';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']         = 'phpmyadmin';
```

Plus perhaps a bunch of entries for the table names (bookmarktable, relation, table_info, etc). I suggest commenting those all out, particularly the controluser, controlpass, and pmadb lines. This should bypass the configuration storage behavior, allowing you to log in without the error. The problem most likely is that the user and password defined here don't exist or don't have the proper permissions on the pmadb database. Once you gain access, if you wish to use those advanced features you can follow the instructions in the documentation to create the user. You may not need these extra features, but if you wish to, you can add the user account then re-enable those lines in config.inc.php.

Currently, that can be accomplished with a command like:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON <pma_db>.* TO 'pma'@'localhost'  IDENTIFIED BY 'pmapass';
```